How to obtain a SYS_REFCURSOR having an explicit cursor in a stored procedure Oracle PL/SQL
I want to write a piece of code in an Oracle stored procedure in which I have defined an explicit cursor and I want to translate it in a generic SYS_REFCURSOR.
I want to avoid to define any specific object-type based on the SQL of the explicit cursor.
Thank you in advance.
The code should be:
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure TransformExplicitCursor(out_sysrefcursor out sys_refcursor) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        CURSOR lc_explicit_cursor IS SELECT ....-- here a complex select
    -- todo something in order to obtain a sys_refcursor from lc_explicit_cursor
END TransformCursor;


You can't do that, as far as I'm aware. You can go from a cursor variable to a ref cursor, but not from an explicit cursor. Why do you want to do this - why not just open the ref cursor directly using the explicit cursor query instead? What does having the explicit cursor as well give you? (Are you maybe trying to process it within the procedure and also return its contents to the caller?)

Thank you @AlexPoole.
I actually thought about explicit cursors because I have to use the same query more times in the Stored Procedure.
It’s not really mandatory to use explicit cursor.
Let me know if you are thinking about another solution without explicit cursor and without writing the same query more times.

@eny, I think a normal ref cursor is all you need. open out_sysrefcursor for select... . Don't use the cursor... syntax, that's for local use within the procedure. Also consider views as a simpler solution if you aren't injecting a predicate deep into it. Views also allow you to consume them in SQL rather than just in PL/SQL, combine them with a larger parent query, etc... However they can be hard to tune if complex and used in multiple different ways. In the world of SQL, we do end up having to repeat code a lot - it's not natively modular like 3GLs.

Thank you @PaulW.
If I use open out_sysrefcursor for select... as you suggest, I will have to repeat the same (complex) sql statement every time I use it in the same Stored Procedure: and this is exactly what I want to avoid.
I’m searching a way to reuse a same sql statement (as a variable) declaring it just once.
I thought to views and that will be the plan b.

Ref cursors can open a SQL using a variable to provide the SQL statement rather than a string literal, so you can define your SQL in one place only and use it in multiple places:
declare
  tmp_cursor sys_refcursor;
  tmp_sql varchar2(32767) := 'select * from dual';
begin
  if true
  then
    open tmp_cursor for tmp_sql;
  else
    open tmp_cursor for tmp_sql;
  end if;
end;

If you need to use a complex SQL on many lines with lots of single quoted strings within it, use the alternative quoting syntax q'{...}' so you don't have to escape those single quotes with the SQL and you can also use as many lines as you need. You can also inject parameters via bind variables:
declare
  var_dummy varchar(1);
  tmp_cursor sys_refcursor;
  tmp_sql varchar2(32767) := q'{
  select :dummy1 
    from dual
   where dummy = :dummy2
  }';
begin
  if true
  then
    open tmp_cursor for tmp_sql using 'A','X';
    fetch tmp_cursor into var_dummy;
    dbms_output.put_line(var_dummy);
  else
    open tmp_cursor for tmp_sql using 'B','X';
    fetch tmp_cursor into var_dummy;
    dbms_output.put_line(var_dummy);
  end if;
end;

If however you intend to use the SQL within your procedure, you should do normal cursors and not ref cursors. Ref cursors are used when the consuming code doesn't know and doesn't care what the SQL is, only what the results are (with a specific set of columns, of course), and usually are consumed by calling procs, not within the same procedure that opened them.
So, if you are using this within the procedure defining them and the only change each time you reuse the same SQL is a parameter, use cursor parameters:
declare
  var_dummy varchar(1);
  CURSOR tmp_cursor (dummy1 IN varchar2,dummy2 IN varchar2)
  IS
  select dummy1 
    from dual
   where dummy = dummy2;
begin
  open tmp_cursor ('A','X');
  fetch tmp_cursor into var_dummy;
  dbms_output.put_line(var_dummy);
  close tmp_cursor;
    
  open tmp_cursor ('B','X');
  fetch tmp_cursor into var_dummy;
  dbms_output.put_line(var_dummy);
  close tmp_cursor;
end;


Thank you @PaulW.
I don’t want to use SQL statement as a string, for two reasons:

first the SQL statement may be very complex and I want to have evidence of syntax errors during compilation;
second: in the same Stored Procedure I can use the same statement Sql more times but with different parameters.
For those reasons I thought to explicit cursor…
Is there a way to use SYS_REFCURSOR avoiding Dynamic Sql?
Thanks in advance,
Enrico.


@eny, you can use the alternative quoting syntax 'q{ .... }' so that you don't have to escape single quotes within the SQL, it can be formatted however you want it to be using however many lines you need, and you can still inject parameters using bind variables.

@eny, see my updated answer. will one of these work for you?

Hello @PaulW
You gave me the interesting suggestions!
Using quoting syntax could be a right way.
But the cursor solution could be interesting as well. In my case, at the end of the Stored Procedure, I have to rely on one of the defined cursor in order to obtain a sys_refursor as OUT parameter.
In your opinion, what is the best way to “transform” a cursor in a sys_refcursor, (avoiding the use of types or global temp tables…)?

@eny, the first example I gave: open tmp_cursor, which if an out param already sends it back and you're done. Don't fetch in the current proc, only in the calling proc.

Sorry @PaulW, for that question, I was referring to your second example using explicit cursor (CURSOR tmp_cursor (dummy1 IN varchar2,dummy2 IN varchar2)
In this way, in your opinion, what is the best way to “transform” an explicit cursor in a sys_refcursor, (avoiding the use of types or global temp tables…)?

@eny, you can't. If you want to use ref cursors, you are going to need to not use the cursor is... syntax.

@eny, if you really want to use cursor is... and have a calling proc consume the results, you can always populate a collection and return the collection (the data itself) rather than the cursor. Or if the caller is a SQL statement, make the proc a pipelined function that pipes rows back, which are treated like rows in table by the calling SQL. But both of these pass back data, not the cursor pointer. If you want to pass a cursor pointer, you must use a ref cursor, which can only be defined by open [refcursor] for... [SQL]. You have lots of options here. Just not the one you're hoping for

@eny, of course, the above require types. There shouldn't be any reason to avoid using types, they are quite powerful. If however you want an option that doesn't require it, you can look into SQL Macros introduced in 19.7 as an option that doesn't require typing, but it is still another form of dynamic SQL. Lastly, as I mentioned at the begging, you can always use views to encapsulate reusable SQL. It's just that views are sometimes hard to work with in complex cases and be performant.

At the end I used the quoting syntax q'{...}' with injected variables, in order to reuse the same Sql Syntax more times, opening sys_refcursor with different variables.
Problem solved!
Thank you @PaulW.
